# Windows API in a Sub Function [VBA]

Tags: vba, vba7

I am new to VBA therefore please excuse me in advance if my question is silly. That said, I have the following Windows API:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsIconic Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Integer
```

and inside the module where we have declared the API I have the following function:

```
Function IsMinimized(hWndAccessApp As Long) As Boolean
    IsMinimized = IsIconic(hWndAccessApp) * -1
End Function
```

In addition to that I also have a form that has a button and a click event on that button that looks like:

```
Private Sub btn_one_Click()
    Dim test As Boolean
    test = IsMinimized(hWndAccessApp)
    MsgBox test
End Sub
```

And everything is working perfectly. However, I was wondering if there is a way to skip the function inside the module and call the "IsIconic" API directly from the Private Sub associated with the button inside the form?

Comment: If it works the why you wrote (using a wrapper function, I see no reason why it shouldn't work when calling it directly - have you tried? Personally, I think using a wrapper Function is a good idea.

Comment: @FunThomas - Whenever I try with `Dim test As Boolean` and `test = IsIconic(hWndAccessApp) * -1` it gives me that `IsIconic Sub or Function is not defined` and I am not sure how to define it further than adding `Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsIconic...` inside a module. To be completely honest I agree with you, but there is not really a real case behind this. I am just playing around with functions and subs as an exercise more than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) There is no way to avoid the Declare-Statement for an API function.

b) You have defined your `IsIconic`-declaration as `Private`, therefore it is known only in that module. If the code of `btn_one_Click` is not in that module, it cannot access the function - but that has nothing to do with being an API function. Just remove the `Private`-keyword, and you can access it from "everywhere".

c) As already mentioned in the comments, I think it is a good idea to use a wrapper function that hides the details of the API-call (and the conversion of the integer value that is returned into an boolean).

d) Using `IsIconic(hWndAccessApp) * -1` to convert an Integer-Value 1 to a boolean looks dirty to me. To avoid a calculation to get a boolean, I would suggest to use

```
IsMinimized = (IsIconic(hWndAccessApp) <> 0)     ' Or = 1
```

In almost all cases, you should forget about the fact that a boolean is stored as 0 and -1 for False and True. Let VBA do the conversion from 1 to True for you.

Comment: Oh, I am not seeing where my mistake was. Thank you for pointing it out, I really appreciate it. In addition, I have moved away from `* - 1` and instead picked what you have suggested. Once again, thank you for the help!